scanf not accepting input - was working earlier
I need to accept user input in military time format "hh:mm:ss" and store hours, minutes, and seconds directly into a struct that contains those separate values.
I tested the scanf format used below earlier today (before writing more code) and now the scanf doesn't allow entry of any characters at all. Previously it allowed entry and correctly stored in the struct. I have no idea how to accept the military time input format with std::cin. (And no I am not allowed to use any other functions built into the standard library.)
Any idea why I can't input anything?? Thanks in advance. I must have changed something that broke this. (I have read other similar posts and flushing the input/output buffer does not help.)
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

struct MyTime {int hours, minutes, seconds;};

//using namespace std;
MyTime *DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime *start, const MyTime *stop);

int main()
{
    // declare start/stop/result structs
    MyTime start, stop, *result;
    // prompt user for start and stop times in military format
    cout << "Enter start time in military format: \n";
    scanf("%2d%*c%2d%*c%2d\n", &start.hours, &start.minutes, &start.seconds);
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "start hours is " << start.hours;
    cout << "start minutes is " << start.minutes;
    cout << "start seconds is " << start.seconds;

    //cout << "Enter stop time in military format: ";
    //scanf("%2d%*c%2d%*c%2d", &stop.hours, &stop.minutes, &stop.seconds);

    //cout << "stop hours is " << stop.hours;
    //cout << "stop minutes is " << stop.minutes;
    //cout << "stop seconds is " << stop.seconds;

    //result = DetermineElapsedTime(&start, &stop);
    //printf("%2d:%2d:%2d\n", result->hours, result->minutes, result->seconds);
}


Your instructor is teaching you C++ and having you use scanf(). You are getting ripped off, my dude.

What is the input you are giving it

Using scanf() on potentially malformed input without checking its return value is trouble waiting to happen. Using scanf() in C++ is -- seconding Dúthomhas here -- is very much ill-advised.

Works well https://godbolt.org/z/W1xGWTqYn

Part of the problem is that trailing \n. It doesn’t do what you think it does. Get rid of it and things will work. (Oh, also, make sure to put a newline at the end of your outputs.)

While we're bashing your instructor, passing arguments by pointer and returning pointers is also raising all kinds of red flags with me. This is C with a bit of C++ sugar on top. Idiomatic C++ works very differently.

https://godbolt.org/z/Go4d4Yqhv (I am uncertain what may be wrong on your end. Try closing your terminal window. Checking the task manager to make sure old copies of your program are no longer running. Reboot?)

If you must use scanf you need #include <stdio.h>. There is no requirement that <iostream> provides it. And then you can change all the cout <<s to printf, which you also get from <stdio.h>, and you'll have straight C code.

@dúthomhas the problem was in fact the \n in the cout statement. Removing it solved the problem.

When reading formatted date/time input in C++, consider using std::get_time() instead of scanf().

@DOSHEA scanf("%2d%*c%2d%*c%2d\n", -- You would have been better off getting rid of the std::cout (and other C++ specific code) and tagging this as C, not C++.   The reason is that C programmers are more familiar with using scanf in this type of way.

Why does scanf ask twice for input when there's a newline at the end of the format string?

Disadvantages of scanf

Why is scanf() considered harmful?.

C++ FAQ 12.20 scanf()
